# Efficient way of partitionning a set into a fixed number of parts

Tags: partitions, space-partitioning

I am looking for a way of efficiently partitionning a set of consecutive integers in to a set where the number $K$ of parts is given.

For instance, for the set {1, 2, 3, 4}, I would like the best way of generating the list of $K=2$ parts.

The result should be the list of partitions, for instance :

{{1},{2, 3, 4}}

{{1, 2},{3, 4}}

{{1, 3},{2, 4}}

and so on...

I am looking for references, or names of algorithm.

Thank you very much

Comment: There is an obvious recursive algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @Gribouillis I am looking for state-of-the-art algorithms.

Comment: Most reasonable approaches will be close to optimal, as you can't do any better than the number of partitions in terms of time.

Comment: There will be $K^n$ different partitions (assuming empty partitions are permissible). If you want the algorithm to list them all, printing the solution will dictate the complexity and any naive approach will do. If you need just one solution that can be solved trivially.